# Why is there an "unexpectedly found nil" error in tableView(cellForRowAt: ) func when the value ISN'T nil?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm working on a homepage for a store management system prototype and it's my first time working with multiple UITableViews within a single view. When I run my code I get the error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`. the error occurs at the first line where I try to set a UILabel's text value in either of the `if` blocks within the func.

Here's the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    var cellToReturn = UITableViewCell()
    
    if tableView == employeeTable {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EmployeeCell") as! EmployeeCell
        
        let employee = employeeArray[indexPath.row]
        // Configure the cell here
        cell.employeeName.text = employee.Name
        //need to change this
        cell.department.text = employee.Notes
        cell.IDPhoto.image = UIImage(named: employee.imgName)
        cell.IDPhoto.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        cell.IDPhoto.asCircle()
        
        cellToReturn = cell
    }
    else if tableView == bestSellerCard.tableView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BestSellerCell") as! BestSellerCell
        
        let product = productsArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.productName.text = product.Name
        cell.productIMG.image = UIImage(named: product.photoName)
        
        cellToReturn = cell
    }
    
    return cellToReturn
}
```

I debugged the code to check if the value is nil and in neither case is the value *actually* nil.

Here's an image of a debug session:
[image: Debug Session image 1]

[image: Debug Session image 2]

This is my first time working with multiple tableViews within the same ViewController so this may be a simple fix but none of the solutions I've found so far have worked. If someone could please explain why this might be happening that would be very much appreciated.

---

**Update**

Based upon the feedback I've received it appears that the issue is how I've set up my outlets

Here is the storyboard for the Home Page View Controller:

[image: XCode storyboard]

Here are my outlets within the ```HomePageVC`` view controller:

```
//HeaderTile class defined below
@IBOutlet weak var headerTile: HeaderTile!
@IBOutlet weak var employeeTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var employeeTableCard: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var employeeTableLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
//Best Seller class defined below
@IBOutlet weak var bestSellerCard: BestSellerCard!
```

And here are the `EmployeeCell`, `BestSellerCard`, and `BestSellerCell` classes:

```
//MARK: Employee Table Cell
class EmployeeCell: UITableViewCell {
   @IBOutlet weak var employeeName: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var department: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var IDPhoto: UIImageView!
}

//MARK: Best Seller Card
class BestSellerCard: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
}
//class for the cells in the Best Seller table
class BestSellerCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var productName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productIMG: UIImageView!
 }
```

I'm a bit confused on why the block within the tableView delegate func for the employee table is having issues because before I added the second table it worked fine. The data I'm using is from a cloudKit database to the line the retrieves the data is an async func but I don't know why that would be an issue.

If that's possibly the issue here is the Task within `viewDidLoad()` where I retrieve the data and reload the tableView's data with the data retrieved:

```
 Task {
        do {
            employeeArray = try await loadEmployeeArray()
            employeeTable.reloadData()
            productsArray = try await loadProductArray()
            bestSellerCard.tableView.reloadData()
            customerArray = try await loadCustomerArray()
            ordersArray = try await loadOrdersArray()
            
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Another reason I think this may be happening is because I saw some tutorial on multiple tableViews within one VC saying that I needed to add the lines below for it to work:

```
employeeTable.register(EmployeeCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "EmployeeCell")

bestSellerCard.tableView.register(BestSellerCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "BestSellerCell")
```

I don't know exactly what these lines even do since this is my first time working with multiple tableViews in one VC, so I've never used the `.register()` func before, so if this is causing the issue please let me know and also when I should *actually* use this func.

**Answer:**
Once I removed the `.register()` lines it worked correctly

Comment: You can see from the debugger that `productName` is nil.  Did you connect your outlets?

Comment: Data is not nil but the label is

Comment: @Paulw11 yes I've connected my outlets, I'll add more info to the question so you can see if there was an error in the way I set up my outlets

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using nib file for the same.
Your might have connected the outlet to the view and you are using owner.
First connect the UI Element from both the view file and the owner object.
Like in below screen shot the  outlet is not connected to the View element. You can se this by selecting file's owner then the connect inspector to see if your outlet is connected or not.

[image: You can see the connection is not establised here]

Comment: I'm using the prototype cells in a tableView within a storyboard, I'll add more info to the original question

Comment: @JonGrimes20 If you are using prototype cell through storyboard then you do not need to explicitly call the register function as it is implicitly registered with the table view in the storyboard.